# Registrar en una BBDD un usuario

Tags: php, mysql

```
#Cargamos todos los archivos de Commons que es donde estan las funciones para
#hacer consultas y conectarnos a la base de datos, hacer insert y select
include dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))."/bbdd/config.php";
include dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))."/bbdd/execute.php";

$name = $_POST['nombre'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
#Funcion md5 nos codifica el pass a la hora de guardarlo en la base de datos
$pass = md5($_POST['pass']);
#Nos conectamos a la base de datos para guardar los usuarios
$connection = Connect($config['database']);
if (!$connection) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
```

Me da fallo en los includes() y al llamar a la conexion para guardarla en una variable, en el archivo de configuracion tengo el array con la config de la bbdd y en el otro la funciones para las consultas

Comment: Primero que nada prueba las direcciones de tus archivos realiza un `echo dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))."/bbdd/config.php";` y verifica si la dirección a donde apunta es correcta.

Comment: C:\xampp/bbdd/config.phpC:\xampp/bbdd/execute.php Me da estas rutas pero sigo sin poder solucionarlo

Comment: Otra cosa que podrías probar es poner un `echo "hola";` y comentando todo el contenido del archivo `config` ya que podría pasar que existe un error en el archivo `config.php` y no así en la inclusión del archivo

Comment: Lo he solucionado, gracias por tu ayuda